# Odoo 8 index page controller

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

is there a way to write code for index page from scratch in Odoo 8?

As far as I can see, I cannot redefine route through `@http.route` (for example `@http.route('/', website=True)`) and I don't want to change original code in addon neither.

So if I want to add drag'n'drop place on my index page, I'll have to write custom snippet, is that right ?